# Yocto error - aarch64-oe-linux-gcc: error: AM_CFLAGS: No such file or directory

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am facing an issue in compiling bitbake file on yocto. I am facing an error as mentioned below.

*| aarch64-oe-linux-gcc: error: AM_CFLAGS: No such file or directory
| aarch64-oe-linux-gcc: error: +=: No such file or directory*

My bitbake file looks as below:

```
inherit autotools qcommon

FILESPATH =+ "${WORKSPACE}:"
SRC_URI = "file://video/bin/mm-video-internal/"

SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
S      = "${WORKDIR}/video/bin/mm-video-internal/"

PR = "r0"

PACKAGES = "${PN}"

DEPENDS = "glib-2.0 libxml2"

export TARGET_LIBRARY_SUPPRESS_LIST="libxml2"

EXTRA_OEMAKE += "DISABLE_GPU_UTF_PQ=true"

CFLAGS += "-I${STAGING_INCDIR}/libxml2/"
CFLAGS += "-include string.h"
CFLAGS += "-Dstrlcpy=g_strlcpy"
CFLAGS += "-Dstrlcat=g_strlcat"

LDFLAGS += "-lglib-2.0"
LDFLAGS += "-llog"
LDFLAGS += "-lxml2"

EXTRA_OEMAKE = "DEFAULT_INCLUDES= CFLAGS="-I. -I${STAGING_KERNEL_BUILDDIR}/usr/include -I${STAGING_KERNEL_BUILDDIR}/include -I${STAGING_INCDIR}/libxml2 -I${WORKSPACE}/kernel/msm-4.4/include/ -I${STAGING_KERNEL_DIR}/include/""
```

Could readers please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a mistake in Makefile.am which i had corrected. Repeated AM_CFLAGS.

> AM_CFLAGS AM_CFLAGS += -g -O3